# suppose to make a concatenated double in vb.net but it's adding instead

Tags: vb.net

help me concatenate instead of adding them
label1 supposed to show concatenated results so that i can save it for my little "history"

```
Dim firstnum As Decimal
Dim secondsum As Decimal
Dim answer As Decimal
Dim op As String


Private Sub Button13_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    Label1.Text = firstnum & " +"
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    op = "+"
End Sub

Private Sub Button14_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
    firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    Label1.Text = firstnum & " -"
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    op = "-"

End Sub

Private Sub Button15_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
    firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    Label1.Text = firstnum & " *"
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    op = "*"
End Sub

Private Sub Button16_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click
    firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    Label1.Text = firstnum & " /"
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    op = "/"
End Sub

Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click
    firstnum = TextBox1.Text
    Label1.Text = firstnum & " ^"
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    op = "^"
End Sub

Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button19.Click
    answer = TextBox1.Text
    If op = "+" Then
        answer = firstnum + secondsum
        TextBox1.Text = answer
        Label1.Text = firstnum + secondsum
        Form3.ListView1.View = View.List
        Form3.ListView1.Items.Add(Label1.Text)
    ElseIf op = "-" Then
        answer = firstnum - secondsum
        TextBox1.Text = answer
        Label1.Text = firstnum - secondsum
        Form3.ListView1.View = View.List
        Form3.ListView1.Items.Add(firstnum + secondsum = answer)
    ElseIf op = "*" Then
        answer = firstnum * secondsum
        TextBox1.Text = answer
        Label1.Text = firstnum * secondsum
        Form3.ListView1.View = View.List
        Form3.ListView1.Items.Add(firstnum + secondsum = answer)
    ElseIf op = "^" Then
        answer = firstnum ^ secondsum
        TextBox1.Text = answer
        Label1.Text = firstnum ^ secondsum
        Form3.ListView1.View = View.List
        Form3.ListView1.Items.Add(firstnum + secondsum = answer)

    Else
        If secondsum = 0 Then
            TextBox1.Text = "Undefined"
        Else
            answer = firstnum / secondsum
            TextBox1.Text = answer
            Label1.Text = firstnum / secondsum
        End If
        End If

End Sub
```

sorry i'm new to vb.net and i really want to learn more. thank you (i've skipped the codes of other number buttons)

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Then have a look at String.Concat .

Comment: String.Concat is good.  You might also try using the & as the string concatenation operator.  See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/concatenation-operators

Comment: i used the & and the problem is the string to double convertion

Comment: Perhaps an example showing the 2 inputs and the expected output would make it easier for us to understand your question? If firstnum=3 and secondnum = 2 (are they strings or numbers?) are you expecting 5 or 32? As a string or as a number?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's supposed to be 32, i'm creating a mini calculator wherein i have a label above my textbox and it shows my equation. here's my whole code

Comment: "i used the & and the problem is the string to double convertion" The & is used to concat strings in some places, but not all.  In `Button19_Click`, the & is not used, but instead + and -, on lines such as `Label1.Text = firstnum + secondsum`.  Perhaps it should have been `Label1.Text = firstnum & " + " & secondsum`?

Comment: You *are* allowed to rename controls after you drop them on a form, you know

Comment: I did that but ends up having a 1 +0 instead of 1 + 1